# Issue with changing the default output font size of Tinymce

Tags: css, tinymce, font-size

I have a problem when trying to change the default font size output for Tinymce.

I have created a separate content.css file with the required fonts and added this line in my code:

```
tinymce.init({
    content_css: MYSURL+"css/content.css",
```

With this I managed to change how the text is displayed on the submit form page, which is part of what I need.

The problem is when i try to display the text directly from the database - it is being displayed with the default font size of 10px.

Note: When I change the font size from the Styles dropdown in tinymce it works. The problem seems to be only with the default formatting.

I will appreciate any help here. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: looks like you will need to apply the same stylesheet after you get your conten from the database

Comment: Thanks for that, this is what I finally did. However, the problem is still there if the user has the option to change the font size himself.

Comment: doesn't the fontsize get saved to the content as well?